# Bind Fancybox to different event

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using the fancybox jQuery plugin and right now, it's being called with a `click` event. I want to change this so that fancybox is called with a different event but I'm not sure where in the source code fancybox is being binded to the click event. Can someone point out the line that this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include code so we can tell you? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two answers: ;)

You can use the "trigger" function of jQuery to launch
the click event you have configured for the fancybox,
so if your fancybox is initialized as:

```
$("#someID").fancybox();
```

you can open that fancybox with only a:

```
$("#someID").trigger("click");
```

OR you can make a manual call for wathever event you want:

```
$.fancybox(
{ 'href'            : $("some jquery reference"),
  'autoDimensions'  : false,
  'width'           : 350,
  'height'      : 'auto'
});
```

There are part of the trip'n tricks of Facnybox page:
[tips & tricks](http://fancybox.net/blog)

Comment: the problem for me is that I have two click events binded to a link and I only want to trigger the fancybox. Also does $.fancybox() actually load the fancybox itself or binds a click event to the fancybox?

Comment: the $.fancybox() load the fancybox itself, I recomend you that declare one function with the $.fancybox() , and bind to the element click you need, and when you want to trigger the fancybox without making click just call that function, and ta da.

Comment: hmm I tried to $.fancybox way but it seems to load asynchronously cause I have an alert after the call and I can see the alert before the fancybox completely loads.

Comment: there are some configurables callbacks for oncomplete, onload, onclose and so on, for use in fancybox config ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've not used fancybox but most of these plugins can usually be fired manually without having to be bound to an element. It's very unlikely you ever need to go rooting about in source code.

You don't say what you want to do but I'm sure you could do something like

```
$('#trigger').mouseover(function() {

    $.fancybox(
        '<h2>Hi!</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque</p>',
        {
                'autoDimensions'    : false,
            'width'                 : 350,
            'height'                : 'auto',
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none'
        }
    );

});
```

Fancybox code taken from http://fancybox.net/blog